# Aggregate over a groupby dataframe one line of code

Tags: pandas, dataframe, iterator

So is there a way to do the following with one line of code:

I have this data below in a dataframe:

```
ID  First Last  Program
1NC Jim     Bo  DM
1NC Jim     Bo  DM
1NC Jim     Bo  DM
1NC Jim     Bo  DM
2bd bob     El  HX
2bd bob     El  HX
2bd bob     El  HX
2bd bob     El  HX
3RF jack    doe DM
3RF jack    doe DM
3RF jack    doe DM
```

I would like to groupby ID and then get the count for each group in a separate list or dict by the unique program:

DM = [4,3] 
HX = [4]

```
df.groupby('ID').counts()
```

gives me the count for each group, now how do I dump the counts into a list by unique key of values (DM, HX) in program?

I tried to do something like this, but didnt work:

```
programs = pd.unique (df['Program'].values)
df.groupby('ID').get_group(programs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way

```
df.groupby(['Program','ID']).size().groupby(level=0).agg(list)
Program
DM    [4, 3]
HX       [4]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Genius mate. Thanks.

Comment: @Sammy7 yw :-)  if this work would you mind upvote and accept ?